# AngularJs filtering data based on option selection and tag creation based on selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Here is my code : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjr2076q/1/)

1. Initialy its should display all the data.
2. I'm able to add new `tags` and based on `tag` selection data is filtering but data should be added below the existing filtered data if new `tag` is selected and data should be removed if `tag` is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> finally `Everything` is resolved.

//FILTER

```
    .filter('findobj', function () {
     return function (dataobj, multipleVlaue) {
         if (!multipleVlaue) return dataobj;
         return dataobj.filter(function (news) {
             var tofilter = [];

             angular.forEach(multipleVlaue,function(v,i){ 
              tofilter.push(v);
             });

             return news.CategoryList.some(function (category) {
            return tofilter.indexOf(category.DisplayName)>-1;
         });

         });
     };
     })
```

Here u can refer :  [CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/0cuvuzd8/2/)