# searchable drop down in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, search, filter, dropdown

I am fetching data from API and I need a searchable `dropdown` so that when I start typing it shows me the data coming from the API. Currently I have this piece of code.

```
<select  class="formControl" name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="facilitiesData.business_id">
    <option ng-repeat="option in businesses" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.business_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Searchable drop down- Do you mean by it a "typeahead" in search box?

Comment: yes something like that,

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin or you want to build on your own?

Comment: something my own but not complex

Comment: I found a better solution here please have a look https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv

Comment: @Usman, Looks like this what I suggested.

Comment: @UsmanIqbal That's not a dropdown. You need sth like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-dropdown ?

Answer (score 10):

Probably you are looking for [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/lMy3nrVwXHANHpk9w6rR?p=preview). This could be one of the solution.

This has different type of **typeaheads**. You can pick one as per your needs.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customPopupSelected" placeholder="Custom popup template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" class="form-control">
```

**Note** - You will require a library **ui-bootstrap-tpls** which is officially created by AngularJS team.

Answer (score 8):

Try this. you cannot directly put textbox inside option and filter select based on it. but this is one way that you can don so. another way is to use plugin or angular material design.

```js
// Angular

var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

myApp.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    'name': 'Item 1'
  }, {
    'name': 'Item 2'
  }, {
    'name': 'Account 3'
  }, {
    'name': 'Account 4'
  }, {
    'name': 'Item 5'
  }, {
    'name': 'Item 6'
  }, {
    'name': 'User 7'
  }, {
    'name': 'User 8'
  }];
});

// jQuery
$('.dropdown-menu').find('.dontClose').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.dropdown.dropdown-scroll .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.search-control {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="dropdown dropdown-scroll" ng-app="app">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Select <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <li role="presentation" class="dontClose">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm search-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Query" ng-model="query"></input>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat='item in items | filter:query'> <a href="#"> {{item.name}} </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi first of all thank you. I have a problem., dropdown menu closes when I click on search area. If a tab there it works fine.  Would you tell me why this happens please?

Answer (score 1):

you can use datalist tag also If you want to build your own searchable dropdown ..Here is the working code:

**HTML Part:**

```
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="click(search);">
      <label class="child-label" for="existing-phases">Existing:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search" list="names">
      <datalist id="names" class="form-control" ng-model="name">
        <option value=''>-- select an option --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="option in contacts | filter:search | limitTo:3" value="{{option.name}}"></option>

      </datalist>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS Part:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showContacts = function() {
    $scope.contacts = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Ben",
      age: 28
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Sally",
      age: 24
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "John",
      age: 32
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "Jane",
      age: 40
    }];

  };
  $scope.showContacts();
  $scope.click = function(MyData) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(MyData));
  };

});
```

Working Demo is available here..https://plnkr.co/edit/hamW3F05YUPrWwS3RmmG?p=preview

Comment: Doesn't handle when `search` becomes empty after searching.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right path. All you need to do now is create an `http` service or factory that triggers an API call every `keypress`, and the result of which populates your `$scope.businesses` array.

Comment: can you do this for me /

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot and post your code here? I can help you debug it, if you run into some issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build searchable drop-down on your own then you can make use of filters.[searchable drop-down with filters using textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218231/angular-filter-by-text-search-and-dropdown)

If you want to go for a plugin check [angular multi select](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main)

I've recenlty used in one of my projects. It is a flexible plugin and it allows multi-select also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropdown select plugin

**JS**

```
const app = angular.module('DropdownSelectApp', ['DropDownSelect']);
```

**HTML**

```
<dropdown-select dd-model="exampleModel" dd-data="exampleItemList" dd-label="labelName" >
```

See this like for demo: https://saravanajd.github.io/Angularjs-Dropdown-Search/