# Text filter and Dropdown filter on the same field in Angular table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am pretty new to Angular and struggling at the moment to do a simple thing. Not sure how to go about it.
I have a table which I have created using ng-repeat.
Now on each of the columns I have filters which are controlled by my ng-model.

For example, let's say I have an Employees table with these columns:

```
EmpId, EmpName, Unit, Active (Y/N)
```

Each of these have filters in the `<th>` tags where I can easily filter by

`Id, Name, Active:Y/N`

Now the problem is I need to show a drop down outside of this table which says `Active/InActive` and by default it should always show Active Employees

So I am not sure how can I specify two filters on the same column to achieve this.
Please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter data using dropdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958636/filter-data-using-dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655104/angularjs-filtering-data-based-on-option-selection-and-tag-creation-based-on-sel)

//FILTER

```
  .filter('findobj', function () {
 return function (dataobj, multipleVlaue) {
     if (!multipleVlaue) return dataobj;
     return dataobj.filter(function (news) {
         var tofilter = [];

         angular.forEach(multipleVlaue,function(v,i){ 
          tofilter.push(v);
         });

         return news.CategoryList.some(function (category) {
        return tofilter.indexOf(category.DisplayName)>-1;
     });

     });
 };
 })
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
This is pretty close to what I was looking for.
Appreciate your help.